# Get all image from certain post type but with full size

Tags: php, wordpress, image, gallery

I do not why but this code get images size as a thumbnail 150x150

[the code is in this question: Get all image from certain post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/gel-all-image-from-certain-post-type?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
enter$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'custom-post', posts_per_page' => -1 ) );if( $query->have_posts() ){
while($query->have_posts()){
    $query->the_post();
    $image_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent' => get_the_ID() ) );
    while( $image_query->have_posts() ) {
        $image_query->the_post();
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID() );
    }
}}
```

it is possible to update this code in order change the image size medium or large size?

Comment: Size defaults to thumbnail as per $size
(string|array) (Optional) Image size. Accepts any valid image size, or an array of width and height values in pixels (in that order).

Default value: 'thumbnail' - from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/ - the codex is you friend

Comment: Dave, please explain in detail?

Comment: If you don't specify the `$size` parameter, it will set the value to thumbnail (it's default value). Check out that link from the WordPress Codex (official documentation) to see how to specify the correct `$size` parameter for your desired results. Make sense?

Comment: Yes it make sense but I'm not getting.

Comment: Yes it make sense but I'm not getting.                                                 
Well let me explain better the my goal.                                                    
In the front-page.php I did a slider only with CSS3 and with this code in order to get all image from certain post type.                                       
The slider it's working but with this issue a image thumbnail size.

Comment: I got it
add_image_size ('slider-thumb', 780, 250, true);
thank you so much for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you test with this?

```
wp_get_attachment_image( get_the_ID(), $size = 'large');
```

If you want to know more about this read here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/